# Search for giphy url in v-for listing (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, async-await

I have a list of movie characters which i get from a REST call to my backend using axios. I display them in a bootstrap card for each character. What I'm trying to do is search giphy for the characters name and use the giphy url as img-src for the card.

When I try this and look inside the Vue devtools, the img-src shows "promise".

```html
<template>
  <div class="characters">
    <b-container>
      <b-card-group columns>
        <b-card
          v-for="character in characters"
          v-bind:key="character.id"
          :title="character.name"
          :img-src="getGiphy(character.name)"
          img-alt="Image"
          img-top
          tag="article"
          style="max-width: 20rem;"
          class="mb-2"
        >
          <b-card-text>
            This character is a {{character.role}}
          </b-card-text>
        </b-card>
      </b-card-group>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

i try to get the image source with `:img-src="getGiphy(character.name)"`

```
@Component
export default class Characters extends Vue {
  public characters: Character[] = [];
  public fields: string[] = ['name', 'role'];

  public async getGiphy(name: string) {
    const giphyApi: string =
      '//api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxx&limit=1&q=';
    const response = await axios.get(giphyApi + name);
    return response.data.data[0].image_url;
  }

  private async created() {
    const response = await axios.get('/api/characters');
    this.characters = await response.data._embedded.characters;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue can't resolve promises in properties so you have to do something like this.

**Template**

```
<b-card
  ...
  :img-src="character.giphyImage"
  ...
>
```

**TS**

```
private async created() {
  ...
  await Promise.all(this.characters.map(async character => {
    character.giphyImage = await this.getGiphy(character.name);
  }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I'm getting the urls for every character now.

Somehow the images aren't showing though. The imgSrc in Vue Developer tools say "null"

Comment: @vince Nice! Did you use the right protocol `http:`?

Comment: Okay so... i went to the toilet right now and when I came back, the images showed. For whatever reason it takes forever to load them.

I hit refresh 10 Minutes ago and they are still not showing. Weird.

Comment: @vince Don't hesitate to ask another question if you get stuck, the SO community is happy to help!